How to scrape elements conditionally and separate its contents?
I'm trying to scrape the number of episodes, the number of season, the execution time, the countries of origin and the language/languages from the IMBD site.
This is the code I used:
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/toptv/"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url,headers=headers).content,"html.parser")

def extract_additional_info(link):
    additional_info = {}
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
    
    # Number episodes
    episode_element = soup.select_one('[data-testid="episodes-header"]')
    if episode_element:
        additional_info['Numero episodi'] = episode_element.get_text().split('Episodes')[1]
        print(additional_info['Numero episodi'])
    else:
        additional_info['Numero episodi'] = None
            
    # Number seasons
    season_select = soup.find('select', id='browse-episodes-season')
    if season_select:
      aria_label = season_select['aria-label']
      additional_info['Numero stagioni'] = aria_label.split()[0] if aria_label else None
    # 1 season
    season_element = soup.select_one('[data-testid="episodes-browse-episodes"]')
    if season_element:
      stagione = season_element.find('span', class_='ipc-btn__text').get_text()
      additional_info['Numero stagioni'] = stagione.split()[0] if stagione else None
    print(additional_info['Numero stagioni'])

    # Duration episode
    additional_info['Durata per episodio'] = soup.select_one('[data-testid="title-techspec_runtime"]').get_text().split('Runtime')[1]
    additional_info['Durata per episodio']= additional_info['Durata per episodio'].split('minutes')[0]
    print(additional_info['Durata per episodio'])
    
    # Contry origin
    additional_info['Paese origine'] = soup.select_one('[data-testid="title-details-origin"]').get_text().split('of origin')[1]
    print(additional_info['Paese origine'])

    # Original language
    additional_info['Lingua originale'] = soup.select_one('[data-testid="title-details-languages"]').get_text()
    print(additional_info['Lingua originale'])

    return additional_info

data = []

for link in soup.select('a[href^="/title"]:has(h3)')[:25]:
    serie_info = json.loads(
        BeautifulSoup(
            requests.get(f'https://www.imdb.com{link.get("href")}', headers=headers).content,
            "html.parser"
        ).find("script", {"type": "application/ld+json"}).text
    )
    
    additional_info = extract_additional_info(f'https://www.imdb.com{link.get("href")}')
    if additional_info is not None:
        serie_info.update(additional_info)
    
    data.append(serie_info)

dati = pd.json_normalize(data)

I have problems with scraping the number of season, because if a tvshow has just one season this information is contained in a different path. So I tried to use an if-statement but it doesn't work and it doesn't find the text 1 season but TopTop- rated.
The HTML to this information:
<div class="sc-e1ed1839-0 fRlQPg episodes-browse-episodes" data-testid="episodes-browse-
episodes"><div class="sc-e1ed1839-1 ihQgyV"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font 
style="vertical-align: inherit;">Browse episodes</font></font></div><div class="sc-e1ed1839-4 
jngMUB"><a class="ipc-btn ipc-btn--single-padding ipc-btn--center-align-content ipc-btn--default-
height ipc-btn--core-base ipc-btn--theme-base ipc-btn--on-accent2 ipc-text-button" role="button"
tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" href="/title/tt5491994/episodes/?
topRated=DESC&amp;ref_=tt_eps_rhs_sm"><span class="ipc-btn__text"><span class="sc-e1ed1839-3 
hWiAfx"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: 
inherit;">Start</font></font></span><span class="sc-e1ed1839-2 cloUKk"><font style="vertical-
align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Most voted</font></font></span></span>
</a><a class="ipc-btn ipc-btn--single-padding ipc-btn--center-align-content ipc-btn--default-
height ipc-btn--core-base ipc-btn--theme-base ipc-btn--on-accent2 ipc-text-button" role="button"
 tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" href="/title/tt5491994/episodes?
season=1&amp;ref_=tt_eps_sn_1"><span class="ipc-btn__text"><font style="vertical-align: 
inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">1 Season</font></font></span></a><span 
class="ipc-simple-select__container"><span class="ipc-simple-select ipc-simple-select--base ipc-
simple-select--on-accent2"><label for="browse-episodes-year" class="ipc-simple-select__label">
<font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">2 years</font>
</font></label><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" class="ipc-icon 
ipc-icon--arrow-drop-down ipc-simple-select__icon--post" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor"
 role="presentation"><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z"></path><path d="M8.71 11.71l2.59 
2.59c.39.39 1.02.39 1.41 0l2.59-2.59c.63-.63.18-1.71-.71-1.71H9.41c-.89 0-1.33 1.08-.7 1.71z">
</path></svg><select id="browse-episodes-year" aria-label="2 years" class="ipc-simple-
select__input"><option selected="" value=""></option><option value="2017">2017</option><option 
value="2016"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: 
inherit;">2016</font></font></option><option value="SEE_ALL"><font style="vertical-align: 
inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">View all</font></font></option></select></span>
</span></div></div>


Next problem is that the output is something like this:
62
TopTop-rated
45 
United States
LanguagesEnglishSpanish
6
TopTop-rated
50 
United KingdomGermanyFranceChinaUnited States
LanguagesEnglishFrench
11
TopTop-rated
49 
United KingdomCanadaUnited StatesJapan
LanguageEnglish
10
TopTop-rated
59 
United KingdomUnited States
LanguagesEnglishDutchFrenchGermanLithuanian
5
TopTop-rated
41 
United StatesUnited Kingdom
LanguagesEnglishRussianUkrainian
60
TopTop-rated
1 hour
United States
LanguagesEnglishGreekMandarinSpanish

So the countries and the languages are not separated if there is more than one element and I don't know how to use split() in this case. I also would like to eliminate language/languages before the language.
Lastly, should I convert the execution time from "1 hour" to "60 minutes", it would make easier my analysis? If yes, how can I do so?

I didn't understand what's your first problem but here's the answer to your second problem.
The languages and countries are concatenated because you are calling get_text on entire element, so it glues all the text components together. In order to get single country, use the following line:
    additional_info['Paese origine'] = soup.select_one('[data-testid="title-details-origin"]').find('a').get_text()


I.e. navigate to the first a subelement and get its text.
In order to get all the languages, find all the a subelements and get their texts:
    additional_info['Lingua originale'] = [e.get_text() for e in soup.select_one('[data-testid="title-details-languages"]').find_all('a')]



Thank you, now it works. Basically my first problem is that I can't get the number of season.  This code alone works only for the series with more than one season, otherwise the information is in another container that is the html I've written before .season_select = soup.find('select', id='browse-episodes-season')     if season_select:       aria_label = season_select['aria-label']       additional_info['Numero stagioni'] = aria_label.split()[0] if aria_label else None 

In order to answer that question I have to understand the model of seasons on IMDB which I don't. Just post two links to pages to scrape: one with one season and the second with severals seasons. I'll try to change your code so that the parsing of the first link will look like the parsing of the second.

Concering your issue with the if-statement you are overwriting additional_info['Numero stagioni'] any time because the season_element always exists.
Try to check additionally that season_select not exist or /and adjust your selector to get the specific <span>:
# 1 season
season_element = soup.select_one('[data-testid="episodes-browse-episodes"] span:-soup-contains("Season")')
if not season_select and episode_element:
  stagione = season_element.get_text()
  additional_info['Numero stagioni'] = stagione.split()[0] if stagione else None

You could also shorten it a bit and cover both situations:
if (stagione := soup.select_one('[data-testid="episodes-browse-episodes"] span:-soup-contains("eason")')):
    additional_info['Numero stagioni'] = stagione.get_text().split()[0]
else:
    additional_info['Numero stagioni'] = None


To select the countries / languages try to adjust your selector a bit

add an "a" to get only the first country or language
a dd an "ul" to get all and invoke the join parameter of get_text() to separate or join by "|":


# Contry origin
additional_info['Paese origine'] = soup.select_one('[data-testid="title-details-origin"] ul').get_text('|')
print(additional_info['Paese origine'])

# Original language
additional_info['Lingua originale'] = soup.select_one('[data-testid="title-details-languages"] ul').get_text('|')
print(additional_info['Lingua originale'])


Converting hour into minutes could be done like:
# Duration episode
if 'hour' in (runtime := soup.select_one('[data-testid="title-techspec_runtime"] div').get_text()):
    additional_info['Durata per episodio'] = int(runtime.split()[0])*60
else:
    additional_info['Durata per episodio']= runtime.split()[0]


Finally you will end with these statments:
...
# Number episodes
episode_element = soup.select_one('[data-testid="episodes-header"]')
if episode_element:
    additional_info['Numero episodi'] = episode_element.get_text().split('Episodes')[1]
    print(additional_info['Numero episodi'])
else:
    additional_info['Numero episodi'] = None
    
# Number seasons
if (stagione := soup.select_one('[data-testid="episodes-browse-episodes"] span:-soup-contains("eason")')):
    additional_info['Numero stagioni'] = stagione.get_text().split()[0]
else:
    additional_info['Numero stagioni'] = None
print(additional_info['Numero stagioni'])

# Duration episode
if 'hour' in (runtime := soup.select_one('[data-testid="title-techspec_runtime"] div').get_text()):
    additional_info['Durata per episodio'] = int(runtime.split()[0])*60
else:
    additional_info['Durata per episodio']= runtime.split()[0]
print(additional_info['Durata per episodio'])

# Contry origin
additional_info['Paese origine'] = soup.select_one('[data-testid="title-details-origin"] a').get_text('|')
print(additional_info['Paese origine'])

# Original language
additional_info['Lingua originale'] = soup.select_one('[data-testid="title-details-languages"] ul').get_text('|')
print(additional_info['Lingua originale'])
...

and with following results:
62
5
45
United States
English|Spanish
...
5
1
41
United States
English|Russian|Ukrainian
60
5
60
United States
English|Greek|Mandarin|Spanish
...

